# Slow motion camera preview android

Tags: android, android-camera, slowmotion

It seems that most Android devices, even if they support slow motion recording, do not expose these settings via the official API.

On newer Samsung phones you can enable a slow-motion preview via CameraParameter

```
parms.set("fast-fps-mode", 1);
parms.setPreviewFpsRange(60000, 60000);
```

How to support all other vendors?